# How to get Array of Field Values from Array of Structs in Rust?

Tags: vector, struct, rust, iterator, map-function

I'd like to map an array of structs to an array of field values. How would I do this?

```rust
pub struct Person {
    name: String
} 

fn main() {
    let my_people = vec![
        Person {
            name: "Bob".to_string(),
        },
        Person {
            name: "Jill".to_string(),
        },
        Person {
            name: "Rakim".to_string(),
        },
    ];
    //map my_people to ["Bob", "Jill", "Rakim"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible solutions, depending on whether you want to clone the names or borrow them. Both solutions below:

```rust
pub struct Person {
    name: String,
}

fn people_names_owned(people: &[Person]) -> Vec<String> {
    people.iter().map(|p| p.name.clone()).collect()
}

fn people_names_borrowed(people: &[Person]) -> Vec<&str> {
    people.iter().map(|p| p.name.as_ref()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let my_people = vec![
        Person {
            name: "Bob".to_string(),
        },
        Person {
            name: "Jill".to_string(),
        },
        Person {
            name: "Rakim".to_string(),
        },
    ];
    println!("{:?}", people_names_owned(&my_people));
    println!("{:?}", people_names_borrowed(&my_people));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=998830a3566ea5f7957d85d83d8c87e5)

Comment: A third option could be to consume the person list in the process and return owned Strings without needing to clone.